# function get_form_kwargs() not being called

Tags: django

I'm trying to pass a parameter from a redirect to the CreateView and to the form.

I have no problem retrieving the value from the redirect to the CreateView.

But my issue is when trying get the value to the form. I'm overriding get_form_kwargs function of my CreateView but when I try to do operations from that function, I'm not able to get any result. I tried to do a print but the print won't display anything.

```
class NoteCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    model = Note
    form_class = NoteForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('note:list')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(NoteCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'file_id' : self.kwargs['file_id']})
        print("im alivveeeeeeeEeeeeeeeeeeeee!")
        return kwargs
```

the print statement doesn't seem to be working. It does not show anything in the console.

I'm able to render the form with no errors in the console.

Comment: Perhaps there is a problem in your URLs, and the request is not being handled by your `NoteCreate` view. The `get_form_kwargs` method you have posted looks ok. Make sure you have saved any changes to your files and restarted the server.